# drupal_goto in new tab

Tags: 7, views, navigation, redirection

**Shortly**: How can I open a drupal_goto() result in a new tab?

**More details**:

I've got a list of news, made with Views, that can be imported from a RSS feed (*big custom module, very complicated, etc, etc*) or directly written by the site's editor.

When I click on a news, I access the node full view mode page and, if it is an imported news, I'm redirected to the source site with `drupal_goto(source)`.

**I want to redirect to the external source site in another tab.** And I can't figure it out. I'm not even sure if that's possible with only PHP.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not detect news origin in the Views an render each one diferently (external one with blank target a, for example)?

Comment: Because I need to go to the internal node page first to track visited nodes. Good question btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That isn't possible - `drupal_goto()` happens server-side, and you can only affect tabs/windows with client-side code.

You would need to stop using `drupal_goto()`, and instead insert some javascript into the page which opens the new URL in a new tab upon refresh.

Some (including myself) would also argue that you have no "right" to do this - let the *user* decide whether they want a new tab or not. Be careful of trying to force your will onto them. See [Target Blank is Evil](http://www.paulingraham.com/target-blank-is-evil.html) for a wonderfully opinionated bit of rhetoric on the matter.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I read indeed that it was not possible on server-side and that I will need to use some JavaScript to achieve that. Unfortunately, I'm not in position to argue the "let's force or not the user to open external links in a new tab" part because it was decided so upstream and I'm only here to execute ;-) Thanks anyway for the advise!

Comment: Ah, clients...wouldn't life be so much simpler without them? ;)

Comment: It's worst than that, I don't have any clients. I'm working for a government company :-P

Comment: Ouch. Run fast, run far ;)